# An unwanted window appears when using the customtkinter library and tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

https://github.com/alisiraydemir/massattenuationpdf/blob/py/Vize_takip_sistemi.py > You can access the code here.

[Unwanted window tk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzwBV.png)

[After clicking "Müşteri Ekle" and trying to close the Tk small window, this error occurs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy2nN.png)

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do not post links to code.

Answer (score 1):

Under `if __name__ == "__main__":`, you call for a Toplevel window which is meant to be a window on top of an already created Tk window ([doc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm)). Since you didn't create one, it creates one for you. To fix this just change `root = customtkinter.CTkToplevel()` to `root = customtkinter.CTk()`.